# Doorbell has no voltage, but chime wires always have voltage

Tags: electrical, repair, transformer, doorbell

I just moved to a new place and trying to fix the doorbell. There are 2 doors, frond and back, neither one is working. I found a doorbell wire image on Google:
[image]

However, it's very strange to see the following behaviors:

1. Disconnect both frond and back buttons, because they could be broken. Test the voltage in Chime. Rear&Trans shows 18V and Front&Trans also shows 18V. It's weird because both buttons are disconnected. Is it correct to say that the Chime is directly connected to the Transformer?
2. Disconnect all 3 wires in Chime. Now test Front and Rear buttons. Both show 0 Voltage as expected.
3. Connect all 3 wires in Chime. Now test Front and Rear buttons. Rear has 18V but Front has 0V.

I also have a wire tracer, but unfortunately I still couldn't find the transformer. I was thinking if there's a broken wire on front door button because it shows 0V. If I use wire tracer on front door button, I can here the tracer sound on Chime and rear door button. I'm very confused why my front doorbell has 0V.

Comment: Since rear now has 18 V does the chime sound when the rear button is pressed?

Comment: In the chime unit what happens if you connect trans to rear? trans to front? This is what the buttons are supposed to do.

Comment: The chime never works even I short the circuit on rear button. I just wonder why there's 18V between trans&rear even rear button wires are not connected.

Comment: What happens if you short across the screws in the chime unit? Trans to rear? Trans to front?

Comment: Are you measuring 18V between the rear and the trans terminals at the chime or are you measuring the individual terminals to ground? If there is a voltage difference between the terminals, current should flow through the solenoid. If there is a voltage applied but no current, then the solenoid is open (aka broken). It is not uncommon to measure a voltage to ground on both sides of a load if the load is being switched on the low side (common in low voltage).

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions. I removed the chime because it could be broken. All the tests are done with the wires directly. I'm confused because even if the doorbell wires are not connected, trans to rear or trans to front still show 18V which doesn't make sense to me. If I short across the wires in the chime (situation 3), Rear button has 18V and Front button has 0V. If I further short rear button wires, there's a spark. @JimStewart

Comment: 18V is measured between rear and trans, or front and trans, when the wires at doorbell button are not connected.